# Solr highlighting results come back/load only sometimes

Tags: solr, solr8

I am having a weird issue where sometimes, my highlighting text does not come back after I perform the query. If I refresh, then it will all appear, other times it takes a couple of re-clicking "perform query" to show up. Most times everything shows up the first time I perform the query, or maybe only half of the highlighting text results appear. My index has 7k-10k documents of pdfs..etc. Not sure if this issue is due to slowness?

I noticed when everything comes back correctly, QTime is 10+. When my highlighting text does not come back, QTime is maybe only 3 or 5 seconds. Can I possible force a delay?

Comment: could you show example of your query?

Comment: @Mysterion I haven't touched the config file, so my query is kind of long. Here is my query: /select?defType=dismax&qf=_text_^2&qf=title^3&pf=_text_^2&fl=id,title,url,last_modified&hl.fl=_text_&hl=on&hl.fragsize=300&hl.simple.pre=&hl.simple.post=&hl.method=unified&q=someKeyword&rows=30